# does a 4K GoPro video airdropped into an iOS device take up space?

Tags: ios, ipad, video, airdrop

I took two 4K videos of about 1 and 2 minutes each on a GoPro and since I couldn't get the full resolution videos directly from the GoPro iPad app, I used AirDrop on a MacBook to send them to the iPad.

I have been unable to play them back on the iPad, so I just want to make sure that they don't take 10+GB of space for nothing.

How do I make sure that these videos aren't on the iPad if I can't see them? Image capture on a MacBook didn't show them, but when I add up all the items reported in space usage, about 15-20 GB are unaccounted for. (I tried airdropping at least one of the videos 2-3 times when it wouldn't show up in the photos app...)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In the Settings, go to **General** -> **Usage** -> **Manage Storage** in order to see how much space every app is using. If you can't find the twenty gb there, it might be in a temporary file that *should* disappear if the power is turned off and the phone is rebooted.

Comment: Thanks @Kent! That's where I originally saw that the numbers don't add up. Unfortunately, I'd restarted already before posting (and have restarted a couple of times since reading your suggestion), but that doesn't work either :(